# Draw lines with labels in the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf

Something confuses me when I draw a line with some label in the middle.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- node[below] {a} ++ (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0) -- node[below] {a} ++ (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,0) -- node[below] {a} ++ (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The following is what I got. Here are my questions:

- I can understand the first one, a line of length 4 with label in the
  middle.
- Why the second one is only half the length of the first one?
- In the third one, if I didn't add the label, why is the length the
  same as the first one?
- Why is there no line in the last one?
- One last question, what does -- and ++ mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `++` provides a relative coordinate with respect to the last point. So. `++(2,0)` means, roughly, `move 2 rightwards and 0 up/down`.

Hence, `(0,0) ++(2,0)` gives a path from the origin to `(2,0)` but `(-2,0) ++(2,0)` gives a path from `(-2,0)` to the origin. Similarly `(43.5,6.78) ++(2,0)` gives a path from `(43.5,6.78)` to `(45.5,6.78)`.

`++(0,0)`, therefore means `don't move at all either up/down or right/left`.

The `++` also changes the position afterwards so that with `(-2,0) ++(2,0)`, the last point is now at `(0,0)`, for instance.

The label doesn't add to the length of the path: `++(4,0)` is still just `4 to the right of the last point` however many nodes are in between.

`--` just means a line as the crow flies between points, which is drawn if we're drawing things at all.

```
\path (0,0) -- (2,0);
```

just moves in a straight line from the origin to `(2,0)`.

```
 \draw (0,0) -- (2,0);
```

also draws that line, whereas

```
\draw (0,0) (2,0);
```

would simply move, without drawing, despite the `\draw` and

```
\draw (0,0) (2,0) -- (4,0);
```

would move from the origin to `(2,0)` and then draw a straight line from `(2,0)` to `(4,0)`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I understand `\draw (-2,0) -- node[below] {a} ++ (2,0);` will draw a line from (-2,0) to (0,0), but is it true that the node will be automatically in the middle between (-2,0) and (0,0)?

Comment: Yes, it will automatically be placed in the middle by default. You can change it by saying e.g. `node [below, near end]` or `node [below, pos=.3]` or whatever, but `midway` is default.